# repeating the same div

Tags: html, tags, standards, repeat

I'm wondering whether or not it's looked down upon for using the same div id or class multiple times in your HTML. I'm using div id="col1" and div id="col2" twice in my HTML and am just curious whether or not this is an acceptable format, or if there is some potential downfall of coding this way.

```
<div class="row1">
    <div id="col1" class="right">
    </div>
    <div id="col2" class="left">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="row2">
    <div id="col1" class="right">
    </div>
    <div id="col2" class="left">
    </div>
</div>
```

How about this?

```
<div id="row1">
    <div class="col1">
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="row2">
    <div class="col1">
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have the same id twice as id attributes are supposed to be unique.

Try `div#row1_col1` and `div#row2_col1`.

```
<div class="row1">
    <div id="row1_col1" class="right">
    </div>
    <div id="row1_col2" class="left">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="row2">
    <div id="row2_col1" class="right">
    </div>
    <div id="row2_col2" class="left">
    </div>
</div>
```

An alternative is to make the columns a class. You can access the column for a row with the selector: `div#row1 div.col1`

```
<div id="row1">
    <div class="col1 right">
    </div>
    <div class="col2 left">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="row2">
    <div class="col1 right">
    </div>
    <div class="col2 left">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a downfall of coding this way.

`id`s in HTML are often used for CSS or JQuery to, well, *identify* the element in question.

If you code this way, it will not be easy for your other code to pick those elements up. The basic HTML standards are to use unique `id`s.

Comment: Oh, I guess you want the "selfie". :-p

Comment: Huh? I don't get it! As you can see, I am Very Very new here.

Comment: It's a hat on [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/selfie)... LOL

Comment: Ahh... I just have the very modest goal of being able to upvote answers that I like as I'm learning to code.  Hats would be nice, I suppose, though.